# Simple problem regarding interpretation of two seemingly identical formulas (container logistics)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

consider we are interested in the required average interarrival-time (the time between two arrivals) of container-ships in order to deliver a total quantitiy of containers (**1 million**) to a container port. Available work days are **365 days**.

For the delivery we will use two types of ships, **large ships** and **small ships**. Large ships can carry **3000 Containers/ship**, small ships can carry **750 containers/ship**. There should be **3 times** more small ships used for delivery than large ships.

To solve the problem for the interarrival-times of the two ship categories large and small ship, I defined two variables:

1. **x = [days/large_ship]** and
2. **y = [days/small_ship]**

The restriction is that **x = 3*y** so that the quantity will be ~3 times lower for x.

I then proceeded to make two equations that which I thought would represent the problem:

1. 3000 * 1/x [moves/large_Ship][large_ship/days] + 750 * 1/y [moves/small_Ship][small_ship/days] = 1000000/365 [moves/work_days]
2. 1/3000 * x [large_Ship/moves][days/large_ship] + 1/750 * y [small_Ship/Moves][days/small_ship] = 365/1000000 [work_days/moves]

I have attached two pictures of the equations

- Equation Nr. 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2zN7.png)
- Equation Nr. 2 [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYub8.png)

Equation nr. 1 gives the correct results (I hope). Equation Nr. 2 seems absolutely reasonable to me as well, when judging by the variables, however it gives the wrong results.

Where in the equation-definition-phase did I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I tried to add days/moves + days/moves and of course, e.g.,  2 days/moves + 5 days/moves is not 7 days/moves.